# How do I handle tensorflow concatenate shape error?

Tags: tensorflow, concatenation

I'm working on a simple model as follows but kinda having difficulty with a concat error.

```
def build_classifier_model():
    text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='input1')
    preprocessing_layer = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_preprocess, name='preprocessing')
    encoder_inputs = preprocessing_layer(text_input)
    encoder = hub.KerasLayer(tfhub_handle_encoder, trainable=True, name='BERT_encoder')
    outputs = encoder(encoder_inputs)
    net = outputs['pooled_output']
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1)(net)
    side_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2), dtype=tf.float32, name='input2')
    print(net.shape)
    print(side_input.shape)
    net = tf.concat(values=[net, side_input], axis=1)
    # net = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([net, side_input], axis=1)
    net = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None, name='classifier')(net)
    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input, side_input], outputs=net)
```

I printed the shape of 'net', and 'side_input' and check their shapes are (None, 512), and (None, 2).

However I'm having concat rank error and it indicates that the shapes are (1, 512) and (2).

```
(None, 512)
(None, 2)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-241-a75a6db54831> in <module>
      1 classifier_model = build_classifier_model()
      2 
----> 3 bert_raw_result = classifier_model([tf.constant(text_test), tf.reshape([0.3, 0.3], (2))])
      4 
      5 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   7184 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   7185   e.message += (" name: " + name if name is not None else "")
-> 7186   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   7187 
   7188 

InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.concat_7" (type TFOpLambda).

ConcatOp : Ranks of all input tensors should match: shape[0] = [1,512] vs. shape[1] = [2] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat

Call arguments received:
  • values=['tf.Tensor(shape=(1, 512), dtype=float32)', 'tf.Tensor(shape=(2,), dtype=float32)']
  • axis=1
  • name=concat
```

The sample input i used was

```
bert_raw_result = classifier_model([tf.constant(text_test), tf.reshape([0.3, 0.3], (2))])
```

Comment: You're using the wrong axis. Try with -1.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that I already tried -1 and it gave me the same error.
I'll try that again to make sure after I finish training a model.

Comment: Try with axis 0 instead actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your 2nd input, i.e. `tf.reshape([0.3, 0.3], (2))` which is a `[2]` sized input.

Your model input (i.e. `side_input` from what I see) expects a `[None, 2]` sized input.

So the solution is (given your first input is `[1, 512]` size),

```
tf.reshape([0.3, 0.3], (1, 2))
```

Comment: It worked out so smoothly! Thank you so much!